# Member of the group and managing categories

Tags: categories, members

I have create new members group (EE 2.7.3) and have enabled there

- Can edit and add new categories
- Can delete categories

but when member of that group is trying to add/edit category it says `You are not authorized to access this page`

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that useful:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/216317/#999955

> In the Category group settings Admin>Channel admin>Categories does the
>   member group have permissions there?